# Getting PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer ~~* integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg, ransack

I am tryin to do a simple search using ransack but when i perform the search I get the following error:

```html
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in GrupoFamiliars#index

PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~* integer
LINE 1: ...rupo_familiars" WHERE ("grupo_familiars"."numero" ILIKE 0) L...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "grupo_familiars".* FROM "grupo_familiars" WHERE ("grupo_familiars"."numero" ILIKE 0) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Here is my code

```
def index
  @search = GrupoFamiliar.search(params[:q])
  @grupo_familiars = @search.result.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
end

<%= search_form_for @search,url: grupo_familiars_path, :class => "form-inline", :builder => SimpleForm::FormBuilder do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :numero_cont, :class => "form-control", placeholder: "Numero" %>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
<% end %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your model:

```
class GrupoFamiliar
  # your code and stuff
  # ...

  private

  ransacker :numero do
    Arel.sql("to_char(\"#{table_name}\".\"numero\", '99999')")
  end
end
```

Comment: Now it works! I do not understand why but thank you.

Comment: Explanation is: ransacker doesn't properly work with non-text fields. This code snippet basically allows it to use text representation of numeric 'numero' field in the search query (to_char is Postgres' integer-to-string conversion function) instead of just original 'numero' field. You are welcome.

Comment: @Ezequiel Link to the ransackers docs [here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers#4-convert-an-integer-database-field-to-a-string-in-order-to-be-able-to-use-a-cont-predicate-instead-of-the-usual-eq-which-works-out-of-the-box-with-integers-to-find-all-records-where-an-integer-field-id-in-this-example-contains-an-input-string) hope this helps you use `_cont` and `_eq` together!